Floating (with scroll) text in AsciiDoc?
New to AsciiDoc. I'm wondering if there is a way to have text "float" with scroll (similar to a floating header row in Excel). I have a single word that I've entered between separator lines below the title block that I would like to remain at the top of the document as a reader scrolls.
Don't know if the solution is relatively straight forward, complex, or impossible.
I've not yet dug too deep, but haven't found a solution.

AsciiDoc text doesn't float or not-float. AsciiDoc does not display anything. It is just a way of encoding the elements of the document. The display capabilities depend on what you are using to interpret the AsciiDoc text and convert it into a display.
Now, if you are also using AsciiDoctor, then you are ultimately generating HTML/CSS — and if you know any CSS, you know that you can make an element float with CSS. In your AsciiDoc document, give the element that is supposed to float to the top a role; this is translated in the HTML to a class attribute, and your CSS can then dictate the positioning that corresponds to that class.
